# Handling window messages in wndproc vs MSG, what's the difference?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I noticed that MSG from winuser.h (which is typedef'd to tagMSG) contains all the parameters from wndproc callback. 
I was wondering if there's any real difference handling messages in wndproc vs handling the outside of wndproc by using MSG, along with the different use cases between the two

Basically something like the following

```
LRESULT WinApp::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   
   switch (uMsg)
   {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

vs

```
MSG msg;
if ((PeekMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
    switch (msg.message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        if (wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
            {
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Nonqueued messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-messages-and-message-queues#nonqueued-messages) are dispatched to the target window procedure automatically by [`PeekMessageW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-peekmessagew). It doesn't return these messages.

Comment: The second version will also cause problems if there is ever a second window associated with you thread.

Answer (score 2):

Each window is associated with a `WindowProc` function. Both queued and non-queued messages that are dispatched to a window will arrive in its WindowProc.  This is the preferred place to process messages that are specific to each window.

`MSG` is used when retrieving queued messages from a thread's message queue, before dispatching the messages to their target windows (see `DispatchMessage()`) .  Processing messages directly in the message loop is the preferred way to handle messages that are specific to a thread but not necessarily to a specific window.

Comment: "Both queued and non-queued messages that are dispatched to a window will arrive in its WindowProc." My understanding was that queued messages will only appear in WindowProc if they are sent there by a GetMessage(), DispatchMessage()  message loop?

Comment: @Andy that is correct. It is `DispatchMessage` that delivers a queued message to a WindowProc.

Comment: @Andy So, this means that I can just omit Massage Loop and ignore all the posted messages? Only receive and process direct calls to `WindowProc`? This might be useful for something like `HWND_MESSAGE` windows.

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer no, you still need a message loop in order to dispatch non-queued messages. Messages that are sent to a window from a thread other than the one that created/owns the window will not be dispatched until the window's owning thread performs message retrieval (ie, `PeekMessage()` or `GetMessage()`). This is documented behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Basically it's the same, in terms of code processing and execution.

But, the main difference goes from the [`SendMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage) function's family:

> The **SendMessage** function calls the window procedure for the specified window...

Generally speaking, in Windows world each window has its own window's procedure, that can be called **outside** of the thread's message loop this window belongs to. As opposed to the [`PostMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagea) function, that:

> Places (posts) a message in the message queue associated with the thread that created the specified window

So now it's clear, that messages **might** be handled in the main message loop, but in this case you are able to handle only the **thread**'s messages. But you lose the ability to handle messages that was sent directly to your `WndProc`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that using the normal message loop will handle cases involving multiple window classes, each with its own WndProc. What you show will only work if there is only going to be one set of message handlers for all windows (including popup menus).